# How can I keep Node-RED process working with Cent-OS6?

Tags: centos6, node-red

I run Node-RED on Cent-OS of remote server. I can run Node-RED process with this command

```
node-red-start &
```

After I command this, Node-RED works.

However when I close local terminal which is connected to the server by ssh, Node-RED does not work, and also not respond 200 from https:*****:1880.

I use Node-RED version: v0.20.3 node —version v8.15.1 CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core).

I want to keep Node-RED even after disconnected from remote sever.
How can I keep Node-RED process.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58653391/edit) the question to say how you installed Node-RED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the service manager on CentOs to start Node Red